# How to calculate this multiplication in vectorized form?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanna calculate the following expression in vectorized form, not using for loop. I would be thankful if someone can help me.

```
j  = 1 to J
s  = 1 to S
t  = 1 to T
s' = 1 to S
p.shape = (J,T,S)
prob.shape = (S)
Xi.shape = (T,S,S)
Pbar.shape = (J,T,S)
```

[image: $ ad $]

Comment: Please explain notations.

Comment: [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

Answer (score 1):

[`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) is what you're looking for:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> j, s, t = 5, 6, 7 # random values
>>> p = np.random.rand(j, t, s)
>>> prob = np.random.rand(s)
>>> xi = np.random.rand(t, s, s)
>>> pbar = np.random.rand(j, t, s)

>>> p_jts = np.einsum('tsS,jtS,S->jts', xi, p, prob) / np.einsum('tsS,S->s', xi, prob)
>>> p_jts.shape == (j, t, s)
True
```

Comment: I just found "einsum". It is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: One question, How can force that the summation is over the "s" in "tss". In my formula, xi in either 0 or 1 and pr is probability. So, final result is a weighted mean of p.

Comment: I think I need to change the code a bit like `np.einsum('tsS,jtS,S->jts', xi, p, prob)`